# Take action based on a type parameter's typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I suspect I have a fundamental misunderstanding to be corrected, so will start with the general concept and then zoom in on the particular instance that lead me to think this way.

Generally speaking, is it possible to write a function whose type signature has a parameterised type, and take different action depending on whether the type parameter belongs to a typeclass?

So for example if you had

```hs
data MyTree a = Node { val :: a, left :: Maybe (MyTree a), right :: Maybe (MyTree a) }

prettyPrint :: MyTree a -> String
prettyPrint (Show a => ...) t = show (val t)
prettyPrint                 t = show "?"
```

where `prettyPrint $ Node 'x' Nothing Nothing` would print `x` while `prettyPrint $ Node id Nothing Nothing` would print `?`.

What lead me here is a few instances where I'm working on a complex, parameterised data type (eg. `MyTree`), which is progressing fine until I need to do some debugging. When I insert `trace` statements I find myself wishing my data type parameter derived Show when I use test (Showable) data. But I understand one should [never add typeclass constraints in data declarations](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) as the wonderfully enlightening LYAH puts it. That makes sense, I shouldn't have to artificially restrict my data type simply because I want to debug it.

So I end up adding the typeclass constraints to the code I'm debugging instead, but quickly discover they spread like a virus. Every function that calls the low level function I'm debugging also needs the constraint added, until I've basically just temporarily added the constraint to every function so I can get enough test coverage. Now my test code is polluting the code I'm trying to develop and steering it off course.

I thought it would be nice to pattern match instead and leave the constraint out of the signature, or use polymorphism and define debug versions of my function, or otherwise somehow wrap my debug traces in a conditional that only fires if the type parameter is an instance of `Show`. But in my meandering I couldn't find a way to do this or a sensible alternative.

Comment: It's a known wart that debugging polymorphic functions can be painful because of the lack of `Show` constraint on type parameters. The common approach is to either print whatever you can print, or to add `Show` constraints wherever you can, good coding practice be damned.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia ...or, ideally, don't rely on showing anything at all. Stronger types, good planning, and extensive and fine-grained QuickCheck tests can do a lot to pin down bugs or avoid them in the first place.

Comment: Would you consider `newtype Don'tShow a = Don'tShow a; instance Show (Don'tShow a) where show _ = "?"` and then leaving users to call `prettyPrint (Don'tShow <$> t)` instead of `prettyPrint t` when that's appropriate?

Comment: Sounds promising, but I'm afraid I don't understand @DanielWagner. Wouldn't `MyTree` still need the `Show a` constraint so the `prettyPrint t` part works? The problem is I don't want to constrain my data type for the purposes of debugging. Could I do the other way around with a `newtype` that *adds* showability, rather than removes it?

Comment: @HeathRaftery "Adding showability" is exactly what `Don'tShow` does... it gives you a `Show` instance for `a` (well, for `Don'tShow a`) even if `a` doesn't already have one...

Comment: @DanielWagner I played around with this because it looks promising, but alas couldn't figure it out. I added `deriving (Functor)` to `MyTree` so that `<$>` works, and now `Don'tShow <$> t` is of type `MyTree (Don'tShow X)`. But still, when I want to `prettyPrint` a `t` with a showable `val`, I still need to add `Show a =>` to `prettyPrint` and *every function that calls it*. If you care to explain it for a simpleton like me I'd be most grateful.

Comment: That's the point: you adapt your data to the function, rather than adapting the function to your data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A good mindset is that from the compiler's point of view, *every type* is potentially an instance of every class. When a type is not an instance of `Show`, it just means the `instance` has not been found yet, possibly not been written yet, but not that it doesn't exist.

#### Approach 1

...Therefore, trying to make a decision based on whether or not a type is an instance of a class is indeed quite fundamentally flawed. However, what you *can* do is to write a class that explicitly makes this distinction. For `Show` this could simply be

```
class MaybeShow a where
  showIfPossible :: a -> Maybe a
```

A generalizable version is to wrap the following around the `Show` class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data ShowDict a where
  ShowDict :: Show a => ShowDict a

class MaybeShow a where
  maybeShowDict :: Maybe (ShowDict a)
```

and then

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

showIfPossible :: ∀ a . MaybeShow a => Maybe (a -> String)
showIfPossible = fmap (\ShowDict -> show) (maybeShowDict @a)
```

Either way, this would still mean you have the `MaybeShow` constraint polluting your codebase – which is in a sense better than `Show` as it doesn't preclude unshowable types, but in a sense also worse because it requires adding instance for all the types you need to use (even if they already have a `Show` instance).

#### Approach 2

You already seem to have considered adding the constraint to the data type instead. And although the old syntax `data Show a => MyTree a = ...` should indeed never be used, it *is* possible to encapsulate instances in `data`. In fact I already did it above with `ShowDict`. Rather than obtaining that implicitly via a `MaybeShow` constraint, you can also just add it optionally to your data type:

```
data MyTree a = Node { val :: a
                     , showable :: Maybe (ShowDict a)
                     , left :: Maybe (MyTree a)
                     , right :: Maybe (MyTree a) }
```

Of course, if all you're using the `Show` instance for is for showing the `val` of this specific node, then you could instead also just put the result right there:

```
data MyTree a = Node { val :: a
                     , valDescription :: Maybe (String)
                     , left :: Maybe (MyTree a)
                     , right :: Maybe (MyTree a) }
```

Now of course you're polluting your codebase in a different way: every function that *generates* a `MyTree` value needs to procure a `Show` instance, or decide it can't. This likely has less of an impact though, and especially not if `MyTree` is only an example and you have many more functions that just work on abstract containers instead.

#### Approach 3

At least for the specific case of debugging, but also some other use cases, it might be best use a separate means of turning the `Show` requirement on and off. The most brute-force way is a good old preprocessor flag:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

#define DEBUGMODE
          -- (This could be controlled from your Cabal file)

prettyPrint :: 
#ifdef DEBUGMODE
        Show a =>
#endif
                MyTree a -> String
#ifdef DEBUGMODE
prettyPrint (Show a => ...) t = show (val t)
#else
prettyPrint                 t = show "?"
#endif
```

A bit more refined is a *constraint synonym* and fitting debug function, that can be swapped out in just a single place:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}

#ifdef DEBUGMODE
type DebugShow a = Show a
debugShow :: DebugShow a => a -> String
debugShow = show
#else
type DebugShow a = ()
debugShow :: DebugShow a => a -> String
debugShow _ = "?"
#else

PrettyPrint :: DebugShow a => MyTree a -> String
PrettyPrint t = debugShow (val t)
```

The latter again pollutes the codebase with constraints, but you never need to write any new instances for these.

`CPP` is quite a blunt tool, in that it requires selecting globally during compilation whether or not you want to require `Show`. But it can also be done more confined, with a dedicated type-level flag:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds #-}

data DebugMode = NoDebug | DebugShowRequired

type family DebugShow mode a where
  DebugShow 'NoDebug a = ()
  DebugShow 'DebugShowRequired a = Show a

class KnownDebugMode (m :: DebugMode) where
  debugShow :: DebugShow m a => a -> String

instance KnownDebugMode 'NoDebug where
  debugShow _ = "?"
instance KnownDebugMode 'DebugShowRequired where
  debugShow = show

{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

prettyPrint :: ∀ m a . DebugShow m a => MyTree a -> String
prettyPrint t = debugShow (val t)
```

This looks a lot like approach 1, but the nice thing is that you don't need any new instances for individual `a` types.

The way to use `prettyPrint` now is to specify the debug mode with a type application. For example you could extract debug- and production-specific versions thus:

```
prettyPrintDebug :: Show a => MyTree a -> String
prettyPrintDebug = prettyPrint @('DebugShowRequired)

prettyPrintProduction :: MyTree a -> String
prettyPrintProduction = prettyPrint @('NoDebug)
```

Comment: Wow, Haskell q's on SO routinely attract exceptional answers and this no exception. Captured and advanced my thinking, and gave alternatives with the detail to evaluate them. Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest approach is to explicitly define overlapping instances for the unshowable types you want. As @leftaroundabout pointed out this solution forces you to define instances for potencially many many types, for example `a -> b`, `IO a`, `State s a`, `Maybe (a -> b)`, etc...

I am assuming that you mostly want to show a tree of type `MyTree (a -> b)`. If that's the case this might do the trick

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data MyTree a =
  Node { val :: a
       , left :: Maybe (MyTree a)
       , right :: Maybe (MyTree a)
       } deriving (Show, Functor) -- The functor instance is just a easy way to map every val to "?", but is not strictly necessary for this problem

-- Create a class for pretty printing. The is a package which already provides it
class Pretty a where
  prettyprint :: a -> String

-- Define an instance when the inner type is showable. (here is simply show, but that's up to you)
instance Show a => Pretty (MyTree a) where
  prettyprint = show

-- Define an instance for the function type.
-- Notice that this isn't an instance for "non-showable" types,
-- but only for the function type. 
-- The overlapping is necessary to distinguish from the previous instance
instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Pretty (MyTree (a -> b)) where
  prettyprint = show . fmap (const "?")

main = do 
  putStrLn 
     $ prettyprint
     $ Node (1 :: Int)
            (Just $ Node 2 Nothing Nothing)
            Nothing
  putStrLn 
     $ prettyprint 
     $ Node id
            (Just $ Node (+ 1) Nothing Nothing)
            Nothing

-- outputs

> Node {val = 1, left = Just (Node {val = 2, left = Nothing, right = Nothing}), right = Nothing}
> Node {val = "?", left = Just (Node {val = "?", left = Nothing, right = Nothing}), right = Nothing}
```

Comment: This _might_ fit the bill for the OP, but in general this approach gets messy fast. It's not true at all that in practice only function types are non-showable. For example `Maybe UnshowableType` and `IO Int` and `StateT (Either String) Bool` and ...

Comment: Good observation. I pointed out the issue of "only" function type, but didn't realize how many non-showable type there are.

Comment: Definitely the way my head was going, so thank you for seeing way further than I could and presenting pros and cons. Alas, functions were an arbitrary example I picked, and I actually want to support **all** non-showable types. However... I just tried cutting the `MyTree (a -> b)` instance from your example, and `prettyprint` still works just fine on showable types, only throwing a "no instance" error for non-showable types. Combined with the fact that my `trace`s are only relevant for my showable test data, I can just remove/comment out, or use that mind-blowing `CPP` extension, and I'm home!

Comment: Eh no, retract that. Same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75182250/take-action-based-on-a-type-parameters-typeclass/75216641?noredirect=1#comment132729503_75216641) (stops working once there's a function in between the constructor and prettyprint).

Comment: With respect to the conversation. Your function `workOnTree  t = trace (prettyprint t) ...` must have type `workOnTree :: Pretty (MyTree a) => MyTree a -> MyTree a` (If you use my solution). The compiler will warn you about using `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}`. Notice that you can't have a polymorphic function which uses `prettyprint` and doesn't have a `Pretty ...` constraint.

Answer (score 2):

See the plugin [if-instance](https://github.com/sheaf/if-instance): https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/x9k5fl/branching_on_constraints_ifinstance_applications/

```
{-# Options_GHC -fplugin=IfSat.Plugin #-}

import Data.Constraint.If (IfSat, ifSat)

prettyPrint :: IfSat (Show a) => a -> String
prettyPrint x = ifSat @(Show a) (show x) "?"
```

This is rarely what you want and if used incorrectly can be used to write `unsafeCoerce`, but this plugin is a recent development and it's good to keep in your back pocket. Previous solutions required a lot more boilerplate.

Comment: Well, that looks like exactly what I asked for! Even if it's not what I *want* and other answers provide very useful alternatives. But together with the Reddit thread, this would be right on the button, except... it only works when called with literal or explicitly-constrained types! So unfortunately something as simple as `doWork :: a -> String; doWork = prettyPrint` will show `"?"` for `doWork 'x'`. For me that's a killer, since I'm trying to avoid littering every function in my call tree with `Show a`.

Comment: That just goes against how type classes work in Haskell, by parametricity the funtion `doWork :: a -> String` must be `const str` for some string. The `show` function is grouped in the `Show a` constraint without which you can't use the method.

Comment: Bummer. To see where this falls over for me, imagine a bunch of functions like `workOnTree :: MyTree a -> MyTree a; workOnTree t = trace (prettyPrint t) $ t{left=Just t}` that I've decorated with `trace`. Even if `t` happens to be of type `Tree Char`, by the time `prettyPrint` sees it I can't show it unless I put `Show a` in `workOnTree` and *every function that calls it*.

Comment: Haskell relies on evidence to make things work, eventually you need a `Show` dictionary for anything that is shown. A key part of Haskell is that `id :: a -> a` cannot do anything with an argument `x::a` so the only thing you can do is return it `id x = x` or diverge `id = error ".."`. If I could write `badid x = 6 * a` without getting a `Num` constraint then that breaks parametricity by having the type `badid :: a -> a` where numerical operations come out of nowhere.

Comment: Makes sense, handy explanation. Different strategy required.

Answer (score 1):

OP here. The other answers resoundingly answer the question I asked. After quite some time digesting them and experimenting, I've arrived at a particular solution to my particular *fundamental goal*, which satisfies me.

It certainly not general or sophisticated. But for me it's a great workaround, so I wanted to leave some breadcrumbs for others:

- First I use the `CPP` trick to define two different `trace` wrappers, so I don't need to use `show` in the non-debug code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
import Debug.Trace ( trace )
type Traceable = Char
dTrace :: (Show a) => a -> b -> b
dTrace traceable expr = trace (show traceable) expr
#else
dTrace :: a -> b -> b
dTrace _ expr = expr
#endif
```

- Similarly, I then define two different data types. Both are `deriving (Show)` but only the debug version actually results in something that will satisfy `show`.

```
data MyTree a = Node {
#ifdef DEBUG
                       val :: Traceable
#else
                       val :: a
#endif
                     , left :: Maybe (MyTree a)
                     , right :: Maybe (MyTree a)
                     } deriving (Show)
```

- And that's it, the pollution stops there. Everything is controlled by the `DEBUG` define and the rest of the code remains unperturbed:

```
workOnTree :: MyTree a -> MyTree a
workOnTree t = dTrace t $ t{left=Just t}

go = workOnTree $ Node 'x' Nothing Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn [val go]
```

If I combine the three code sections and compile with `#define DEBUG`, it outputs:

```
Node {val = 'x', left = Nothing, right = Nothing}
x
```

And with `#define DEBUG` commented out (and no other changes!), I get:

```
x
```

and `Node` will happily accept non-showable values for `val`.

Even without the `CPP` stuff (which, even as a long time fan of the C preprocessor, I can understand is not to all tastes), this is pretty manageable. At the least you could just manually swap a few lines to switch between testing and production.